# How do I server-side include processed XML/XSL into an existing HTML document

Tags: xml, xslt, server-side-includes

I have constructed menu.XML & successfully formatted it with menu.XSL. It works as intended when viewing menu.XML in the browser. How do write menu.XML to a HTML file so I can further include that into another HTML document?

Comment: I see the invalid `<menu="this">` at that URI, and hence don't see the XSL happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the results of the transformation or pipe them through and expose them. Currently you are exposing the xml and referencing the xsl.